# WTF Form doesn't validate

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

For some reason my wtf form doesn't seem to validate. When the form is completed with a username that already exists and I press submit, the page stays where it is and does not raise a validation error despite being in the code. Users with new usernames are added to the database just fine.

Hopefully someone can copy/paste the code into a text editor and get it to run:

Here is the Form:

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):

    username = StringField('Username', validators = [DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators = [DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    def validate_username(self,field):
        if UserRegistration.query.filter_by(username=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('Your username has been registered already!')
```

Here is the model class:

```
class UserRegistration(db.Model, UserMixin):

__tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.Text(128))


    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Username {self.username}"
```

Here's the view:

```
@users.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        username = form.username.data
        password = form.password.data

        user = UserRegistration(username, password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        flash(f'Thanks for registering! Your credentials are: Username: {username}, Password: {password}')

        return redirect(url_for('users.all_users'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

Here's the html document where the form goes:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <h1>Registration Form</h1> <br>

    <form method="POST">
      {{form.hidden_tag()}}

      <div class="form-group">
        {{form.username.label()}}
        {{form.username(class='form-control form-text text-muted')}}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {{form.password.label()}}
        {{form.password(class='form-control form-text text-muted')}}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {{form.submit(class="btn btn-primary")}}
      </div>

    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If you are suspecting validation problems, print/flash/log the `form.errors` dict.

Comment: just as a point in passing, your `username` and `email` have `unique=True` set so if the form submits repeated values it might be worth error trapping a `UniqueKeyConstraintError` rather than validating the form. It is less code to maintain and potentially covers more bases.. just a thought

Answer (score 0):

`WTForm`  **in-line validator methods** must use the following convention: `validate_<field_name>`.

In your example, your form fields of interest i.e. those which need validation are the following: `[username, email]` so your validation methods must be: `validate_username(...)` and `validate_email(...)` respectfully. Instead of `check_email(...)` and `check_username(...)` which isn't what `WTForm` expects for in-line validators...

Try *renaming your validation methods* to conform to the `WTForm` in-line specification, something along the lines of:

```
def validate_email(self,field):
    # check is none for that user email!
    if UserRegistration.query.filter_by(email=field.data).first():
        raise ValidationError('Your email has been registered already!')

def validate_username(self,field):
    if UserRegistration.query.filter_by(username=field.data).first():
        raise ValidationError('Your username has been registered already!')
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hi Nathan. Unfortunately that caused the same problem as before. The form doesn't get redirected and all the info in the form is still complete except for username and password which needs re-entering.

Comment: Maybe you could log some stmts to see where it gets stuck? Your indentation looks off for the register route, idk if this was the result of a copy/paste ? Maybe check your indentation levels as well

Comment: I have updated the code with a very skimmed down version of the basics to try to understand where the problem is. I can add new users to the database just fine but if I add a user with an existing username no validation error is raised despite being in the code. I have modified the code and all indents are the same here as they are in my code. Hopefully you can see an error here now. Thanks Nathan.

Comment: did you find the solution for this?